# Get the values from the multiple checkbox and append it to html?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the modal from twitter bootstrap, i want to make a modal that when a user click on button it appear with checkboxes that have a specific values, and when modal hide the values added to my html ( next to the a.btn ) ..

here is the html

```
<body>

<!-- Get the button problem  -->

<!-- Button to trigger modal -->
```

Launch demo modal

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <label for="value">
        <input type="checkbox" name="value1" value="1">value1
    </label>
     <label for="value">
        <input type="checkbox" name="value2" value="2">value2
    </label>
     <label for="value">
        <input type="checkbox" name="value3" value="3">value3
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

and here is my script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#myModal .btn').last().on('click', function(){
        var checkbox_val = $('input:checkbox:checked').val();
        var MyModal = $('#myModal');
        function get_value() {
            var allVals = [];
            $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
                allVals.push(checkbox_val);
            });

            $('a.btn').after("<p>" + allVals + "</p>");
        }
        MyModal.modal('hide').on('hidden', function(){
           get_value();

        })

    });
  });
</script>
```

**Edit**
Here is the value for allVals when i choose all checkbox
["1", "1", "1"]

I want the value to be 
["1", "2", "3"]

Comment: and what do you got? Which line is giving problems? what is the final value of `allVals`?

Comment: i added the value as edit in my question

Comment: and you want to get `1, 2, 3`?

Comment: You have to use the `$('this')` selector inside the `.each` loop, check my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is when you do `allVals.push(checkbox_val);` inside the `.each` loop, you are pushing the same value all the times, that's why you got [1,1,1]. So update your jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#myModal .btn').last().on('click', function(){
        var MyModal = $('#myModal');
        function get_value() {
            var allVals = [];
            $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
                allVals.push($(this).val()); //Use the $('this') selector
            });

            $('a.btn').after("<p>" + allVals + "</p>");
        }
        MyModal.modal('hide').on('hidden', function(){
           get_value();

        })

    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

In console the array returns "1","1"

```
$('input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
    allVals.push(checkbox_val);// it will return first checkbox value '1' alway
});
```

For this replace this line `allVals.push(checkbox_val);` to `allVals.push($(this).val());`